# xrandr detects amplifier as monitor

Tags: xorg, xrandr, hdmi

To help with setting up multi-monitor X I'm using a simple [script](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/04f535c6b71e92100bc6b85963f906ab0171e86e/.screenlayout/monitor_resolutions.sh) to get screen resolution information using `xrandr`. This was working fine until I tried attaching an amplifier to attempt to use HDMI audio output. Now the `xrandr` output contains extraneous information about a monitor which is not present. Is there some way to avoid `xrandr` detecting this device as another monitor? The device is an [Onkyo TX-NR509](http://www.uk.onkyo.com/en/products/tx-nr509-35637.html).

An obvious workaround is to detach the amplifier every time I start X.

Comment: Wow, I wonder if that is a bad amp or a bug in the HDMI stack on Linux?