# How to get EDID for a single monitor?

Tags: xrandr, edid

Pending an answer to [xrandr detects amplifier as monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98478/xrandr-detects-amplifier-as-monitor) a possible workaround is to blacklist devices with specific [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data)s. Unfortunately [`xrandr --verbose`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9754/3645) prints everything in a format which is cumbersome to parse and doesn't support querying single devices, and [`get-edid`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=13706)'s output doesn't seem to be easy to map to `xrandr`'s monitor IDs (for example `DVI-1`).

**Is there some way to get an *easily parseable* EDID for a *single* monitor?**

Comment: I'd go for `xrandr` parsing. It's cumbersome, but you just write your script once and for all, and then it'll work everywhere.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Lead #1: monitor-edid

I'm not that up on EDID and monitors but I did find this tool, `monitor-edid` which might be of use to you here as well.

Forgive me if it's off base, I'm trying to also learn more about this space, given the variety of questions you ask on the topic.

```
$ monitor-edid 
EISA ID: LEN4036
EDID version: 1.3
EDID extension blocks: 0
Screen size: 30.3 cm x 19.0 cm (14.08 inches, aspect ratio 16/10 = 1.59)
Gamma: 2.2
Digital signal

    # Monitor preferred modeline (60.0 Hz vsync, 55.8 kHz hsync, ratio 16/10, 120 dpi)
    ModeLine "1440x900" 114.06 1440 1488 1520 2044 900 903 909 930 -hsync -vsync

    # Monitor supported modeline (50.0 Hz vsync, 51.8 kHz hsync, ratio 16/10, 120 dpi)
    ModeLine "1440x900" 114.06 1440 1488 1520 2204 900 903 909 1035 -hsync -vsync
```

#### Lead #2: ddccontrol

There was another tool that I came across called [`ddccontrol`](http://ddccontrol.sourceforge.net/), which might be helpful in getting the information you're after.

#### Lead #3: /sys

Finally in poking through `/sys` I noticed that there were leaf nodes hanging off of the various video interfaces.

```
$ sudo find /sys |grep -i edid
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1/edid
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-2/edid
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-3/edid
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-VGA-1/edid
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1/edid
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1/edid
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-2/edid
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-3/edid
/sys/module/drm/parameters/edid_fixup
/sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/edid_firmware
```

However on my Lenovo laptop these "files" were empty, perhaps they're different on your system. I found this forum thread that showed sample output from the VGA EDID.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation NV17 [GeForce4 440 Go 64M] (rev a3)
$ xxd  /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0/0000:01:00.0/drm/card0/card0-VGA-1/edid
0000000: 00ff ffff ffff ff00 5a63 0213 0101 0101  ........Zc......
0000010: 2b0a 0103 1c25 1bb0 eb00 b8a0 5749 9b26  +....%......WI.&
0000020: 1048 4cff ff80 8199 8159 714f 6159 4559  .HL......YqOaYEY
0000030: 3159 a94f 0101 863d 00c0 5100 3040 40a0  1Y.O...=..Q.0@@.
0000040: 1300 680e 1100 001e 0000 00ff 0033 3139  ..h..........319
0000050: 3030 3433 3030 3737 330a 0000 00fd 0032  004300773......2
0000060: a01e 6114 000a 2020 2020 2020 0000 00fc  ..a...      ....
0000070: 0047 3930 6d62 0a20 2020 2020 2020 00ba  .G90mb.       ..
```

***Source:** [Extract Monitor Serial Number / Manufacture Date Using EDID?](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=250723).*

#### References

- <del>[Monitor-edid](http://wiki.mandriva.com/en/Tools/monitor-edid)</del>
- [The *new* homepage of read-edid](http://www.polypux.org/projects/read-edid/)
- [Extended display identification data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data)

Comment: @l0b0 - has it only been 2? Seemed like more. I may be confusing the category of this Q w/ just you asking them. I will remove the offending bit 8-)

Comment: #3 /sys/... works for me, I have `Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)` with `i915` driver, Kubuntu 15.04

Comment: #3 /sys/... and `xrandr --verbose` both return EDID data for my HDMI monitor, but neither return EDID data for my DVI monitor.

Comment: The monitor-edid link is dead and archive.org doesn't have any backups. Anyone know where I can get that tool?

Comment: @PeterW. - there's the alternative, thanks for bringing this to my attention. Also the tool is in most of the major repos. I found it in Fedora 24, for example and also CentOS. So you can install the tool as a binary which is probably a much easier option.

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint, and `apt-get install monitor-edid` returned an error for me.

Comment: @PeterW. - you might want to try getting the actual .deb files and manually installing them from an Ubuntu/Debian repo. The source is in the updated link if you want to build it by hand.

Comment: `sudo find /sys -name edid* -exec sh -c 'echo;echo;echo {}; echo ------' \; -exec cat '{}' \; | less`

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer or not, but I found that even though `find /sys/devices -type f -name "edid" | xargs ls -l` produces listings with size 0, hexdump -C does produce a dump of 256 bytes of text, with the correct 'Acer H233H' name among them. I appreciate this answer for helping me get where I got.

Answer (score 24):

The output of `xrandr --props` contains hex EDID strings for each connected display in a less verbose way.  Here's a [simple Python script](https://gist.github.com/mvollrath/9aa0198264e6b4890914) exploiting this to grab an EDID for a specific connected monitor.

I haven't found any other distro-packaged CLI tools that work for EDID extraction on my NVidia-based system, but most tools for parsing a binary EDID seem to work fine.

Comment: xrandr --props worked for me, I then cut of the EDID found in the output and was able to use edid-decode (https://git.linuxtv.org/edid-decode.git/) to get human-readable info from it.

Answer (score 19):

In the binary form EDID is available at `/sys/class/drm/card%d-%s/edid`, where `%d` represents DRM device index (probably a GPU index) and `%s` is a connector ID that you see in `xrandr` output.

To list all available, run `ls -1 /sys/class/drm/*/edid`

If your GPU driver doesn't support DRM, you won't be able to get EDID this way.

To view in hex form, run `hexdump` on it.

If you want human-readable form, pass it to `edid-decode`, e.g.:

```
edid-decode < /sys/class/drm/card0-eDP-1/edid
```

<sup>(you might need to install it using your package manager, `sudo apt install edid-decode` for Ubuntu)</sup>

Comment: More accurately to get the hex form, you need to run the content of the edid file through `hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x"'`

Comment: Your first point is not accurate on my system. xrandr gives me: `eDP-1, DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, DP-4, DP-4-1, DP-4-2, DP-4-3, DP-3-1, DP-3-2, DP-3-3`, but the `/sys/devices/` outputs are `eDP-1, DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, DP-4, DP-5, DP-6, DP-7`

Comment: The stdin redirection is not necessary: `edid-decode` can also take a file as argument: `Usage: edid-decode <options> [in [out]]` where `[in]` is the EDID file to parse. Read from standard input if none given or if the input filename is `-`.

Answer (score 13):

If you happen to be using a x86 or powerpc arch, you could use `read-edid`. On debian this is available [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/utils/read-edid).

Usage is simply (you need to be root):

```
$ sudo get-edid > /tmp/edid
```

and then parse the structure:

```
$ parse-edid < /tmp/edid
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HP v220"
    ModelName "HP v220"
    VendorName "HWP"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 13 of 2008
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Analog Display
    DisplaySize 470 300
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-81
    VertRefresh 56-76
    # Maximum pixel clock is 160MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x720, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x960, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x1000, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
    Modeline    "Mode 0" -hsync +vsync 
EndSection
```

Often this is combined into:

```
$ sudo get-edid | parse-edid
```

---

See also [here](https://superuser.com/a/1145719/106444) on how to pass this custom edid file to your graphic card using either:

- CustomEDID or,
- drm_kms_helper.edid_firmare

Comment: Just to clarify that get-edid did not work for me until I did "modprobe i2c-dev" . And the "parse-edid" produced Modeline was not accepted by Xorg. So I've used this in the device section:

    Option         "CustomEDID" "CRT-0:/etc/X11/edid-StarLight-170418_gb-nv-gf-650-GTX-VGA.bin"

I need to manually provide the EDID since it can not be correctly read over  10m long VGA cable. Setting the "DisplaySize" was also useful for me.

Answer (score 4):

A recent version of a tool called edid-decode can parse EDID information, and it can read and write text and binary EDID files. It works well on the output of `xrandr --verbose`. For example, It can be used to save the EDID in a binary file:

```
xrandr --verbose | edid-decode - /file/to/save
```

The version of edid-decode that comes with Fedora 27 (package: xorg-x11-utils) is too old and it doesn't work perfectly. I used the most [recent version](https://git.linuxtv.org/edid-decode.git/tree/edid-decode.c).