# How can I get monitor resolution without lightdm service?

Tags: x11, resolution, lightdm

In a desktop application, I need to detect monitor resolution from time to time. The code is like:

```
Display *d;
Screen *s;
d = XOpenDisplay(":0");
if (NULL == d) {
    g_print("XOpenDisplay failed\n");
    return;
}
s = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(d);
if (NULL == s) {
    g_print("DefaultScreenOfDisplay failed\n");
    return;
}

g_print("Display size: %dx%d\n", s->width, s->height);
```

But another requirement needs me to turn off lightdm service and X server too, which this piece of code depends on.

Is there other method to detect resolution without Xlib support?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at `xrandr`?

Comment: With lightdm off, xrandr shows "Can't open display". So I figure it depends on X11 too?

Comment: Oh you are turning X11 off as well. Can you make this clear in the question. (you don't need a display manager to run X11, so we just assumed that you were still running X11).

Comment: Actually I'm doing this to avoid a confliction between my app and something in lightdm service. I'm not sure if it's the display manager or X11 itself. So I want to turn them all off.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the (native/maximum) monitor resolution is possible even without an X server by querying the EDID information directly. See [How to get EDID for a single monitor?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114359/how-to-get-edid-for-a-single-monitor). Experience may vary depending on graphics card and drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the command `xrandr`

Comment: Or `libxrandr`.

Comment: Answer should provide a complete explanation. your answer would be better as a comment.