# Is it possible to simultaneously enumerate X Server display connections and identify the monitor attached to each?

Tags: x11, xrandr, xubuntu

I would like to enumerate the X Server display connection points, e.g. `DisplayPort-1-7` or `HDMI-A-1-1`, while simultaneously identifying the physical monitor (if any) attached to each.

**Motivation**: I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 (Bionic), and xfce does a poor job auto-configuring my displays when docking/undocking. I'm on a Dell laptop, and the GPU changes the identifiers of the display connections when docked, undocked, and re-docked, so I can't just use a fixed identifier to set up the monitors, which makes the scripts created by `arandr` fail.

My objective is to write a simple Bash/Python script that can look at the connected monitors and run xrandr to configure the displays the way I want them to be set up.

**Potential tools**:

- `xrandr` gives me a list of display connection points, which are specific to X Server, but doesn't give me monitor IDs.
- `hwinfo --monitor` can list the monitors and decode the EDID data to determine their model names and serial IDs, but doesn't know the X Windows names.

I've yet to find a way to determine which physical monitor is connected to which X Server port.

**Edit** to clarify about a comment below: My goal is to identify the monitor from its name, model number, or serial number. Then I can use the monitor's identity to set its resolution and position using `xrandr` in a script.

Comment: Do you want something to list the serial number, or do you want something to pop up on the screen and say "this is HDMI-0 on DISPLAY:3"? Is this more a "how do I make my displays have constant names" question?

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114359/how-to-get-edid-for-a-single-monitor) question help? There may be other stuff in the `/sys/.../HDMI-A-1-1/` etc. directories that may already be enough to identify the monitor if you don't need the full EDID, but right now I can't look.

Comment: @dirkt Actually that looks like the solution. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114398/152671), specifically, includes a description of navigating the `/sys` filesystem tree to find each card's display connection points, plus the current monitor's EDID data to go with it. That's the solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @dirkt Correcting my previous comment. The answer I linked is unfortunately not a solution, as the names used in `/sys` do not match the names used by `x11` to describe the connection points. On my system, `/sys` has a path named `DP-4`, whereas the X Server name for the port is `DisplayPort-1-3`. So I can't use these names to configure X using `xrandr`. The search continues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just the good part**: [Here's my Python script for doing this](https://gist.github.com/courtarro/3adec649c086eea1bb18919d6269d544), which requires `python-xlib` be installed.

I have found one source, so far, to get the list of X Server display connections and simultaneously get the monitors connected to each, and that is X itself. There are multiple ways to get this information from X, depending on your tolerance to parsing vs. getting the data directly from X.

## Method 1: Parsing `xrandr --verbose`

The `xrandr --verbose` command has all the information needed to match display connections with monitors. Its output for a single display connection looks like this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 6400 x 1600, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    [extra content removed]
DisplayPort-1-7 connected 1920x1080+0+464 (0x4a) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
    Identifier: 0x224
    Timestamp:  6668772
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       4
    CRTCs:      0 4 5 6 7
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0010ac73404c424241
        ------[more hex redacted]-------
        001155223811000a202020202020007e
    GAMMA_LUT_SIZE: 4096 
        range: (0, -1)
    DEGAMMA_LUT_SIZE: 4096 
        range: (0, -1)
    GAMMA_LUT: 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    DEGAMMA_LUT: 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    TearFree: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    vrr_capable: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    max bpc: 8 
        range: (8, 16)
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 76 
        supported: 76
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x4a) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1680x1050 (0x9b) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
[extra content removed]
```

Parsing this output isn't great: you'll need to identify the lines that represent a display connection vs. the screen, with variations based on whether it's connected/disconnected, etc. But if you do, you can extract the EDID, convert it to raw bytes, and pass it to a tool like `parse-edid`.

## Method 2: `Xlib` client and EDID parser

There is a [Python client for Xlib](https://pypi.org/project/python-xlib/) that has the tools needed to fetch the display connections and the relevant EDID bytes from each connected monitor. Similarly, there is [a Python library for parsing EDID data](https://pypi.org/project/pyedid/), though it is not quite ideal (explained below). However, I've made an example script that puts the two of these items together to yield the answer I want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pyedid.edid, pyedid.helpers.registry
import Xlib.display

def get_x_displays():
    # Used by PyEDID to fetch manufacturers given their EDID code
    registry = pyedid.helpers.registry.Registry.from_web()

    # Xlib resources
    d = Xlib.display.Display()
    root = d.screen().root
    resources = root.xrandr_get_screen_resources()._data

    outputs = {}
    for output in resources['outputs']:
        output_info = d.xrandr_get_output_info(output, resources['config_timestamp'])._data
        output_name = output_info['name']
        props = d.xrandr_list_output_properties(output)
        edid_data = None

        # Look through the atoms (properties) of each output to see if there's one named 'EDID'
        for atom in props._data['atoms']:
            atom_name = d.get_atom_name(atom)
            if atom_name == 'EDID':
                edid_raw = d.xrandr_get_output_property(output, atom, 0, 0, 1000)._data['value']
                edid_data = pyedid.edid.Edid(bytes(edid_raw)[:128], registry)
                break

        outputs[output_name] = edid_data

    return outputs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    displays = get_x_displays()
    for connection, monitor in sorted(displays.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0]):
        print(connection)
        print('    ' + ("No connection or empty EDID" if monitor is None else
                        "{} ({})".format(monitor.name, monitor.serial)))
```

On my machine, this produces the following output (serial numbers mangled):

```
DP-1
    No connection or empty EDID
DP-2
    No connection or empty EDID
DP-3
    No connection or empty EDID
DisplayPort-1-3
    No connection or empty EDID
DisplayPort-1-4
    No connection or empty EDID
DisplayPort-1-5
    No connection or empty EDID
DisplayPort-1-6
    DELL UP3017 (DDSB553SBDFL)
DisplayPort-1-7
    DELL U2312HM (V092DMLS657D)
DisplayPort-1-8
    No connection or empty EDID
HDMI-1
    No connection or empty EDID
HDMI-A-1-1
    No connection or empty EDID
eDP-1
    None (0)
eDP-1-1
    No connection or empty EDID
```

The PyEDID library requires a "registry" of manufacturers so that it can populate the manufacturer field of the EDID. The `from_web()` call to create the registry from an online source is the slowest part of this script. I have created [an alternative version of the script](https://gist.github.com/courtarro/3adec649c086eea1bb18919d6269d544) that eliminates that requirement by skipping the manufacturer lookup altogether, instead passing out the raw value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried`

```bsh
    $ xrandr --listactivemonitors
    Monitors: 2
    0: +*DVI-0 1920/521x1080/293+0+0  DVI-0
    1:  +DVI-1 1920/521x1080/293+0+0  DVI-1
```

It breaks it down into a table format like this:

[Screen/Display] number: [Connector + Mode]  [Connector]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't identify the monitors themselves. The closest thing I've found so far is `xrandr --verbose`, which includes the EDID data of each connected monitor. The EDID data can then be parsed to read out the model number and serial number (if supported) from the display.